# Animation works only one way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:
http://jsbin.com/havesixufo/edit?html,output

Only it works scrolling down, but when scrolling up the divs get 2 classes instead of 1. You would say just reverse what you do when going down but not working.

Comment: Please show relevant code in your question

Comment: don't post all that code, but just main bits. And explain what are doing really!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if block's code in the UP section to below

```
if(bottom >= prevElement.center.bottom && bottom <= element.top.top){
    prevElement.target.addClass('center').removeClass('bottom');
}
if(stCenter <= element.top.center && bottom >= prevElement.center.bottom){
    element.target.addClass('top').removeClass('center');
}
```

here is a working version of your script http://jsbin.com/manaqitudu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: OP's code for scroll UP is checking whether bottom position of the first element is less than bottom position of all other elements (remember prev is in a for loop). First el's bottom position is always less than all the other elements and hence the classes were changed on all elements on every scroll up, So I limited the condition by checking if it is less than current element top position and greater than previous element bottom position. This only validates for the immediate previous element instead of every previous elements in the series.

Comment: The whole code could have been written in a much neater and less confusing way but I only corrected what OP has provided.

Comment: @Webpandit I am open for approvement so if you think it can neater, please help me out.